# Remove first element of a Stream in Java 8

Tags: java, filter, functional-programming, java-stream, java.nio.file

I have generated a Stream in Java 8 with Files.walk() method from java.nio library. The problem is that the method includes by default the root path but I do not want this element. I have solved in this case with this code using filter() method:

```
public void listFiles(String directoryPath) {
    try {
        Path root = Paths.get(directoryPath);
        Files.walk(root,1)
            .filter(x -> !x.equals(root))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error reading file: " + directoryPath);
    }
}
```

My question is if there is a way more elegant to remove the first element of a Stream than this. For example working with a index in the Stream or with a tail() method as others functional languages.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

## `Stream#skip`

Use [skip(1)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-) to ignore the first element.

Don't use it with parallel streams without reading the disclaimer in the javadoc.

Comment: That's a more elegant way to do this. Very similar to tail() in lisp o scala. Thanks!